# How can I interact with a third party service that sends POST requests to me in response to the order information that I send them?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-remote-request

I'm developing a payment gateway for Wordpress. I should send the data to a third party and get the confirmation code (and other info) from them. The problem is that they don't return this confirmation code as a direct response to my POST request. Instead, they process it, and send a POST request to a URL that I can specify. Because of this, I can't use the wp_remote_post.

How can I implement this, and if possible, ensure that the user stays on my page?

Thanks.

Edit: They wanted me to edit this with code, so here it is:

```
<?php
class SPYR_AuthorizeNet_AIM extends WC_Payment_Gateway {

// Setup our Gateway's id, description and other values
function __construct() {

    // The global ID for this Payment method
    $this->id = "spyr_authorizenet_aim";

    // The Title shown on the top of the Payment Gateways Page next to all the other Payment Gateways
    $this->method_title = __( "Authorize.net AIM", 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' );

    // The description for this Payment Gateway, shown on the actual Payment options page on the backend
    $this->method_description = __( "Authorize.net AIM Payment Gateway Plug-in for WooCommerce", 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' );

    // The title to be used for the vertical tabs that can be ordered top to bottom
    $this->title = __( "Authorize.net AIM", 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' );

    // If you want to show an image next to the gateway's name on the frontend, enter a URL to an image.
    $this->icon = null;

    // Bool. Can be set to true if you want payment fields to show on the checkout 
    // if doing a direct integration, which we are doing in this case
    $this->has_fields = true;

    // Supports the default credit card form
    $this->supports = array( 'default_credit_card_form' );

    // This basically defines your settings which are then loaded with init_settings()
    $this->init_form_fields();

    // After init_settings() is called, you can get the settings and load them into variables, e.g:
    // $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );
    $this->init_settings();

    // Turn these settings into variables we can use
    foreach ( $this->settings as $setting_key => $value ) {
        $this->$setting_key = $value;
    }

    // Lets check for SSL
    add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this,  'do_ssl_check' ) );

    // Save settings
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        // Versions over 2.0
        // Save our administration options. Since we are not going to be doing anything special
        // we have not defined 'process_admin_options' in this class so the method in the parent
        // class will be used instead
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }       
} // End __construct()

// Build the administration fields for this specific Gateway
public function init_form_fields() {
    $this->form_fields = array(
        'enabled' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Enable / Disable', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'label'     => __( 'Enable this payment gateway', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'default'   => 'no',
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Title', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'text',
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'Payment title the customer will see during the checkout process.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'default'   => __( 'Credit card', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
        ),
        'description' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Description', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'textarea',
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'Payment description the customer will see during the checkout process.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'default'   => __( 'Pay securely using your credit card.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'css'       => 'max-width:350px;'
        ),
        'api_login' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Authorize.net API Login', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'text',
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'This is the API Login provided by Authorize.net when you signed up for an account.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
        ),
        'trans_key' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Authorize.net Transaction Key', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'password',
            'desc_tip'  => __( 'This is the Transaction Key provided by Authorize.net when you signed up for an account.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
        ),
        'environment' => array(
            'title'     => __( 'Authorize.net Test Mode', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'label'     => __( 'Enable Test Mode', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'type'      => 'checkbox',
            'description' => __( 'Place the payment gateway in test mode.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ),
            'default'   => 'no',
        )
    );      
}

// Submit payment and handle response
public function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    global $woocommerce;

    // Get this Order's information so that we know
    // who to charge and how much
    $customer_order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Are we testing right now or is it a real transaction
    $environment = ( $this->environment == "yes" ) ? 'TRUE' : 'FALSE';

    // Decide which URL to post to
    $environment_url = ( "FALSE" == $environment ) 
                       ? 'https://secure.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll'
                       : 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';

    // This is where the fun stuff begins
    $payload = array(
        // Authorize.net Credentials and API Info
        "x_tran_key"            => $this->trans_key,
        "x_login"               => $this->api_login,
        "x_version"             => "3.1",

        // Order total
        "x_amount"              => $customer_order->order_total,

        // Credit Card Information
        "x_card_num"            => str_replace( array(' ', '-' ), '', $_POST['spyr_authorizenet_aim-card-number'] ),
        "x_card_code"           => ( isset( $_POST['spyr_authorizenet_aim-card-cvc'] ) ) ? $_POST['spyr_authorizenet_aim-card-cvc'] : '',
        "x_exp_date"            => str_replace( array( '/', ' '), '', $_POST['spyr_authorizenet_aim-card-expiry'] ),

        "x_type"                => 'AUTH_CAPTURE',
        "x_invoice_num"         => str_replace( "#", "", $customer_order->get_order_number() ),
        "x_test_request"        => $environment,
        "x_delim_char"          => '|',
        "x_encap_char"          => '',
        "x_delim_data"          => "TRUE",
        "x_relay_response"      => "FALSE",
        "x_method"              => "CC",

        // Billing Information
        "x_first_name"          => $customer_order->billing_first_name,
        "x_last_name"           => $customer_order->billing_last_name,
        "x_address"             => $customer_order->billing_address_1,
        "x_city"                => $customer_order->billing_city,
        "x_state"               => $customer_order->billing_state,
        "x_zip"                 => $customer_order->billing_postcode,
        "x_country"             => $customer_order->billing_country,
        "x_phone"               => $customer_order->billing_phone,
        "x_email"               => $customer_order->billing_email,

        // Shipping Information
        "x_ship_to_first_name"  => $customer_order->shipping_first_name,
        "x_ship_to_last_name"   => $customer_order->shipping_last_name,
        "x_ship_to_company"     => $customer_order->shipping_company,
        "x_ship_to_address"     => $customer_order->shipping_address_1,
        "x_ship_to_city"        => $customer_order->shipping_city,
        "x_ship_to_country"     => $customer_order->shipping_country,
        "x_ship_to_state"       => $customer_order->shipping_state,
        "x_ship_to_zip"         => $customer_order->shipping_postcode,

        // Some Customer Information
        "x_cust_id"             => $customer_order->user_id,
        "x_customer_ip"         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],

    );

    // Send this payload to Authorize.net for processing
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, array(
        'method'    => 'POST',
        'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
        'timeout'   => 90,
        'sslverify' => false,
    ) );

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
        throw new Exception( __( 'We are currently experiencing problems trying to connect to this payment gateway. Sorry for the inconvenience.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

    if ( empty( $response['body'] ) )
        throw new Exception( __( 'Authorize.net\'s Response was empty.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

    // Retrieve the body's resopnse if no errors found
    $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

    // Parse the response into something we can read
    foreach ( preg_split( "/\r?\n/", $response_body ) as $line ) {
        $resp = explode( "|", $line );
    }

    // Get the values we need
    $r['response_code']             = $resp[0];
    $r['response_sub_code']         = $resp[1];
    $r['response_reason_code']      = $resp[2];
    $r['response_reason_text']      = $resp[3];

    // Test the code to know if the transaction went through or not.
    // 1 or 4 means the transaction was a success
    if ( ( $r['response_code'] == 1 ) || ( $r['response_code'] == 4 ) ) {
        // Payment has been successful
        $customer_order->add_order_note( __( 'Authorize.net payment completed.', 'spyr-authorizenet-aim' ) );

        // Mark order as Paid
        $customer_order->payment_complete();

        // Empty the cart (Very important step)
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();

        // Redirect to thank you page
        return array(
            'result'   => 'success',
            'redirect' => $this->get_return_url( $customer_order ),
        );
    } else {
        // Transaction was not succesful
        // Add notice to the cart
        wc_add_notice( $r['response_reason_text'], 'error' );
        // Add note to the order for your reference
        $customer_order->add_order_note( 'Error: '. $r['response_reason_text'] );
    }

}

// Validate fields
public function validate_fields() {
    return true;
}

// Check if we are forcing SSL on checkout pages
// Custom function not required by the Gateway
public function do_ssl_check() {
    if( $this->enabled == "yes" ) {
        if( get_option( 'woocommerce_force_ssl_checkout' ) == "no" ) {
            echo "<div class=\"error\"><p>". sprintf( __( "<strong>%s</strong> is enabled and WooCommerce is not forcing the SSL certificate on your checkout page. Please ensure that you have a valid SSL certificate and that you are <a href=\"%s\">forcing the checkout pages to be secured.</a>" ), $this->method_title, admin_url( 'admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=checkout' ) ) ."</p></div>";  
        }
    }       
}}
```

Comment: how is this wordpress specific? And with so little detail it is probably just can't be answered.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. It's clearly about Wordpress. And may I ask you what further information do you need? Thanks.

Comment: @Nozulani We get a _lot_ of questions pertaining to payment gateway integrations (almost always disguised work-for-free requests), and you just end up on autopilot ;) Check my answer for a suggested solution, any questions just holla.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Thanks for your response, but I don't know what you mean by "disguised work-for-free requests". I guess every question on this website can be labeled as such if one is cynic enough. And people are downvoting my question, I really don't understand the crowd in here. They are making people almost afraid to ask questions. I've researched and tried different things before asking. I'm not saying someone has to answer, but downvotes and cynic comments are ridiculous and laughable. Thanks again.

Comment: Appreciate your comments @Nozulani. What I mean by "disguised work for free" is that it's become very hard for us to distinguish between genuine & curious coders willing to _learn_, and those with simply no inclination to understand their problem - they just want a solution and they want one now and they're too tight to pay for a developer. Whilst we most certainly what to remain welcoming to all, we have no choice but to fight back with skepticism - the influx of leeches is a daily battle for upholding this community.

Comment: @Nozulani The problem is that you are _telling_ that you did research, but you are not _showing_ what routes you have already taken, where you failed and how far you got. This normally is labeled as _"too lazy to tell"_ or _"too lazy to try, just telling they did"_, which is a problem. Just try to switch chairs: Everyone reading your question currently has to go down every route that you might have already taken and fail as often as yourself. You can take that away and make things much more easier and attract much more answers by spending 15 minutes on documenting your efforts.

Comment: For the question: I will leave it open for now in the hope you file an [edit] and fix that. Aside from that: Use a dedicated page with a custom page template, provide this Url to the gateway. Then dump any `$_REQUEST` templates in a temporary log file to see the response. Paste that output to your question as well "we" can work with that and stub/mock that request. Also tell **(a)** which gateway it is, (b)** link to their API docs and **(c)** post your example `wp_remote_post()`. People need to be able to replicate your problem in local dev installs to answer.

Comment: Your question deserved to be downvoted, whether you like it or not. It is poor quality, I cannot see how you expected positive feedback or upvotes from somthing this bad

Comment: @Pieter Goosen My God. OK, I'm literally Hitler, I'm a monster for posting such a horrible question, are you guys happy now? I didn't expect anything. Answer it if you want, pass it if you don't. What the matter with you all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I doubt "pretty" URLs are important here, it's incredibly easy to create an endpoint/handler using the AJAX api (the other option is to use the rewrite API and listen out for a hit).

Don't be put off by the term "AJAX" - this is simply a script within your WordPress install that will fire a matching hook for whatever is passed as the `action` parameter (either via GET or POST).

For example, `example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=gateway`:

```
function wpse_225366_gateway_response() {
    // Do your thang

    exit;
}

// The wp_ajax_nopriv_{action} hook fires for non-authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_gateway', 'wpse_225366_gateway_response' );

// The wp_ajax_{action} hook fires for authenticated users
add_action( 'wp_ajax_gateway',        'wpse_225366_gateway_response' );
```

You'll probably want to call the action something less generic than `gateway`, but I hope this illustrates how things work.

You can use the following to get the response URL programmatically:

```
$response_url = admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php?action=gateway' );
```